# Difficulty creating "View" in MVC3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, view

I'm having problem when trying to create a view in MVC3. The problem is that I'm only able to create a view file with the name "Index", everytime I tries to create it with other names, it will gives me a "The resource cannot be found." error, am I missing anything?
btw, i'm running on localhost.

Comment: Post some controller code. If you don't explicitly pass the view name to your `return View();` statement it will look for a view named the same as the current Action

Comment: strange.. Create view called Index and rename it.. :)

Comment: Can you post your folderstructure with folder and files? What do you have in your views-folder and your controllers-folder?

Comment: It seems like, its not problem with your view, but its missing in actionresult in controller, Post ur code to get exact problem, so that we could help you more better.

Comment: "The resource cannot be found" (really a 404) would indicate some kind of routing problem. Would you be able to post your Global.asax?

Comment: look [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials) these tutorials a great place to start.

Comment: is the "The resource cannot be found" a message within Visual Studio? Are you running the English version? Do you have installed some plugins, such as ReSharper? I would guess you should answer these questions first and paste the controller and the rounting configuration code.